# Subplots in columns and rows

Tags: python

I would like my sybplots to be generated in 2x columns and 5x rows.

 I've also tried adding ncols=2, nrows=5 to the code. didn't work.

 And when I change the subplots to plt.subplots(5,2) instead of plt.subplots(10,1) it says (see added picture of code+error message):

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9844/709244097.py in 

 13

 14 for ax, afstand, tid in zip(ax, afstande, tider):

 ---> 15     ax.plot(tid, afstand)

 16     ax.set_title("x(t)", fontsize=12)

 17     ax.set_xlabel("tid (s)", fontsize=12)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

---

My code:

 from scipy.optimize import fmin

 a = -75.64766759

 b = 68.02691163

 f = lambda x: a * x + b

afstand1, afstand2, afstand3, afstand4, afstand5, afstand6, afstand7, afstand8, afstand9, afstand10 = f(U1), f(U2), f(U3), f(U4), f(U5),f(U6), f(U7), f(U8), f(U9), f(U10)

afstande = [afstand1, afstand2, afstand3, afstand4, afstand5, afstand6, afstand7, afstand8, afstand9, afstand10]

 tider = [tid1, tid2, tid3, tid4, tid5, tid6, tid7, tid8, tid9, tid10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(10,1, figsize=(7,25))

 plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.55)

#loop

 for ax, afstand, tid in zip(ax, afstande, tider):

     ax.plot(tid, afstand)

     ax.set_title("x(t)", fontsize=12)

     ax.set_xlabel("tid (s)", fontsize=12)

     ax.set_ylabel("Position", fontsize=12)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsXzn.png)

Comment: Please [format](/help/formatting) your question correctly and no screenshots of text please. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Welcome to SO, image is a very poor medium to exchange textual data. Just don't, never, copy paste instead. Also you can use text formatter while editing your post in order to make your code more readable. Read [mcve] and [ask] for more details.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `plt.subplots`? The second item in the tuple it returns is an _array of axes_. Why do you expect this array to have the same methods as the `Axes` object itself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using the same variable name for the array of axis and in the loop, you should change that. Subplot-axes are stored in numpy arrays. If you only have 1 row, then looping over the array gives you the elements, but in a x*y pattern of subplots, you loop over a two-dimensional array of axis, which yields the rows. You can solve that by using `.flat` to get a one-dimensional view.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=5, nrows=2)
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.plot(...)
```